# Valid set operation or not valid notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In a text I was reading; this was included in a section on set operations...

(-∞, 0) ∪ (0, ∞)

Is that a valid set operation if the typical "{}" are missing?

If it is valid; I assume this would also be valid...

[1, 3] = {x: 1 <= x <= 3}

Comment: The equation you wrote for $[1,3]$ is perfectly good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $(-\infty, 0)$ is a validly defined set.
- $(0, \infty)$ is a validly defined set.
- if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A\cup B$ is a validly defined set.

In fact, $$(-\infty, 0)\cup (0, \infty) = \{x| x<0\}\cup \{x| x>0\} = \{x| x<0\lor x>0\} = \{x| x\neq 0\} = \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$$

All expressions above denote the same set and are equally valid (although the first and last are most common because they are easiest to recognize)

Comment: You mean (−∞,0)∪(0,∞) and R∖{0} are the most common, yes? Makes sense as I wrote down that (−∞,0)∪(0,∞) = R∖{0} and then I questioned the notation on the left hand side of the equation.

Comment: @DoctorQuestions Exactly, those two are most common. But again, both are equally valid.

Comment: I would say the expressions in the middle are the easiest to understand, since they rely only on very basic arithmetic and set definition notation, but the first and last expressions are the easiest to _recognize_ if you have seen them before and have understood them.

Comment: @DavidK Good point. *Recognize* is a better term to describe what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 1):

We have $(-∞, 0) ∪ (0, ∞)= \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}=\{x \in \mathbb R: x \ne 0\}$.

Comment: Good, I wanted to make sure the notation was valid. Yes, it's the reals without 0.